# Order dataframe by column with specific order from list

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to order/ran a data frame by a column with an specific order, say I have

```
col1 col2
v_1  4
v_2  3
v_3  1
```

And say you want to order as:

```
col1 col2
v_3  1
v_1  4
v_2  3
```

As I wanted to order by [3,1,2] in column col1. Simplified example as my df has 42 rows. What I expected is being able to pass a list of values [3,1,2] and sort col1 based on such indicators, so 1 refers to v_1, etc

Comment: What kind of mapping that you have for *1 refers to `v_1`? e.g, a dictionary `{1:'v_1'}` or a function `[f'v_{i} for i in [1,2,3]]`?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a temporary column `order` and have the index of item in list from the column `col1`, then sort dataframe on this temporary column, and remove the column before returning the dataframe.

Something like this:

```py
def sortDF(df, lst, colName='col1'):
    df['order'] = df[colName].apply(lambda x: lst.index(x))
    return df.sort_values(['order']).drop(columns=['order'])
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     3
2     3     1

>>> sortDF(df, [3,1,2], 'col1')
   col1  col2
2     3     1
0     1     4
1     2     3
```

**PS:** The method above expects that all the values in `col1` also exist in the list, otherwise it will throw `IndexError`, you can handle that scenario manually if that's not the case, and represent it by `NaN` on `order` column, then you can use parameter `na_position` while sorting the dataframe.

Comment: `lst.index(x)` suggest a very slow sorting for long `lst/df`...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a Multiindex,  based on a mapping, select the rows, via loc, and drop the extra index after:

```
mapping = [3, 1, 2]

# create pairing between `col1` and range of numbers :
mapp = pd.Series(df.col1.array, index = range(1, df.col1.size + 1))

# append mapped index to df
(df.set_index(df.col1.map(mapp), append=True)
   .swaplevel() # move index to the front
   .loc[mapping] # reshape order
   .droplevel(0) # purpose served, drop it
)
  col1  col2
2  v_3     1
0  v_1     4
1  v_2     3
```